# How to charge a Customer instead using the Stripe orders API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, payment

I have been having some trouble charging my customers for an order in the Stripe orders API. The problem I had is that I can't find any information in the [API docs](https://stripe.com/docs/orders) of how to charge an order from an already existing customer. All I can find is that to charge a customer based on a token you may use the following code. `order.pay(:source => token)`

I create my orders in the following way as explained by the API docs.

```
Stripe.api_key = "sk_your_secret_key"

order = Stripe::Order.create(
  :currency => 'usd',
  :email => 'jenny@example.com',
  :items => [
    {
      :type => 'sku',
      :parent => 'sku_9wSEbSepjclY6l',
      :quantity => 2,
    }
  ],
  :shipping => {
    :name => 'Jenny Rosen',
    :address => {
      :line1 => '1234 Main Street',
      :city => 'Anytown',
      :country => 'US',
      :postal_code => '123456'
    }
  },
)
```

I have previously created my customers from a StipeJS API token like so.

```
token = params[:stripeToken]

customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
  :email => "paying.user@example.com",
  :source => token,
)
```

I now wish to use the customers stripe id to create the charge on the order but I can't find how I do this any where in the API docs.

---

**Update**

In a trial and error attempt I tried passing the customer id to the payment function like so `order.pay(:source => customer_id)`. This yeilded the following error.  `(Status 400) no such token: cus_id_string`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find out how this is done by trial and error. I finally attempted paying for the order pushing a hash like so. `orders.pay(:customer => customer_id)`.

This actually worked for me even though I don't see it documented any where. I hope it helps you as well.

Comment: The `customer` parameter is mentioned in the API reference: https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_order-customer

Comment: Thanks for the information I also found this here once I knew what I was looking for. (https://stripe.com/docs/api#pay_order)